# Calling methods in Activity from RecyclerView adapter class

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with a recyclerview and a button. In my recyclerview adapter in my onBindViewHolder, I set an onClickListener to the layout of the list item. When this is clicked, I want to pass the Contact (list item type) that was selected to my activity and then into a list so that it can be sent as a request to my server.

When the item is clicked, I want the colour to change to a highlighted blue colour, and for the button at the bottom of the screen to say "Continue - x contacts" (x = however many contacts are selected.) I had this working until I added the button to the activity.

The problem I'm having, is that the button isn't associating with the button ID, and it is crashing out after an item click because setText() cannot be called on a null object reference.

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

I don't understand why the button is null, unless it is the way that I'm calling my activity object from the adapter.

Appreciate any help or advice!

RecyclerViewAdapter: (I have the other methods and ViewHolder class in the adapter and they are working fine. This is the only method that is effecting the result afaik)

```
private CreateGroupAccountStage2 createGroupAccountStage2 = new CreateGroupAccountStage2();
public List<Contacts> contactsList;
public List<Contacts> selectedContacts = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
final Contacts contacts = contactsList.get(position);
viewHolder.contactName.setText(contacts.getContactName());
viewHolder.contactItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Set on click listener to item layout
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    if (!contacts.getIsPressedValue()) {
      contacts.setPressedTrue(); // Method that changes boolean value stored in the Contact object
      viewHolder.contactItem.setBackgroundResource(R.color.createGroupAccountContactItemPressed);
      selectedContacts.add(contacts);
    } else {
      viewHolder.contactItem.setBackgroundResource(R.color.whiteText);
      contacts.setPressedFalse(); // Method that changes boolean value stored in the Contact object
      selectedContacts.remove(contacts);
    }
    createGroupAccountStage2.updateSelectedContacts(contactsList);
  }
});
}
```

Activity:

```
Button stage2Continue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_group_stage2);

  stage2Continue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createGroupAccountStage2ContinueBTN);
  setUpActionBar();
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

  ArrayList<Contacts> fullContactsList = new ArrayList<>();
  fullContactsList.add(new Contacts(R.drawable.human_photo, "Human One", "humanone@gmail.com"));
  fullContactsList.add(new Contacts(R.drawable.human_photo, "Human Two", "humantwo@gmail.com"));

  setUpContactsRecyclerView(fullContactsList); //Sets up recycler view (works fine)
}

public void updateSelectedContacts(List<Contacts> contacts) {
  int listSize = contacts.size();
  updateContinueButton(listSize);
}

public void updateContinueButton(int selectedContactsListSize) {
  String listSize = Integer.toString(selectedContactsListSize);
  String buttonText = "Continue - " + listSize + " contacts";
  if(selectedContactsListSize > 0) {
    stage2Continue.setText(buttonText);
  } else {
    stage2Continue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
}
```

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="grouppay.dylankilbride.com.activities.CreateGroupAccountStage2">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/createAccountStage2Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/whiteText"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/createGroupAccountStage2ContinueBTN"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/generic_continue"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textColor="@color/whiteText"
    android:background="@drawable/generic_rounded_continue_button_bg"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/createGroupAccountStage2ContactsRV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Contact List Item Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:id="@+id/createGroupAccountStage2ContactLL">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/createGroupAccountStage2ContactImgTV"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/human_photo"
    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/profileImageBorder"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/createGroupAccountStage2ContactNameTV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/cairo"
    tools:text="Human Example"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `createGroupAccountStage2.updateSelectedContacts(contactsList);` inside **RecyclerViewAdapter**. How are you creating the instance of `createGroupAccountStage2`? I think that should be a interface which the **Activity** should implement and passed to **RecyclerViewAdapter**.

Comment: In the adapter I just create a global instance of it; CreateGroupAccountStage2 createGroupAccountStage2 = new CreateGroupAccountStage2;. Could you show me how it would be done using an interface as I'm not overly familiar with them..

Comment: [CustomItemClickListener](https://gist.github.com/riyazMuhammad/1c7b1f9fa3065aa5a46f) and [ItemClickSupport](https://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/) might help

Comment: These haven't helped..

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to implement `onCreateViewHolder()` in your RecyclerViewAdapter so that the ViewHolder is inflated with the layout including your createGroupAccountStage2ContinueBTN button

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have that already there. I just posted the methods that were directly effecting the result. I will clarify this in the question

Comment: Also post the layout file you use to inflate your items

Comment: Done, but I don't think that it has any relevance to the question or answer. The issue is with the button at the bottom of the recycler view and not the RV itself..

Answer (score 0):

Check your import, if correct contactName view is imported in your code, there is a chance that you are using same id for another view in any other xml file and because of that wrong import you are getting null for that view as that view is not inflated.